# Android webView - javascript code is not getting called

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I try to load this javascript in my webview:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    website = "https://www.blizz-z.de";
    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.blizzView);

    WebSettings settings = blizzView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        // Notify the host application that a page has finished loading.
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            myWebView.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:(function() {" +
                        "setInterval(function() {" +
                            + "jQuery('#myInput').css('background', '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));"
                        + "}, 1000);"
                    + "});"
            );
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

But it is not getting executed. If I execute the script in my desktop browser, then it works. It changes the background color of my search bar on my [website](https://www.blizz-z.de) just for test purposes.

Is `setInterval` not supported in webView?

**Update:**

I tried it with the function `js` from @mohkamfer's answer:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    website = "https://www.blizz-z.de";
    blizzView = findViewById(R.id.blizzView);

    WebSettings settings = blizzView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        // Notify the host application that a page has finished loading.
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            js(myWebView, "(function() {" +
                        "setInterval(function() {" +
                            + "jQuery('#myInput').css('background', '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));"
                        + "}, 1000);"
                    + "});"
            );
        }
    }

    ...

}

public void js(WebView view, String code)
{
    String javascriptCode = "javascript:" + code;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        view.evaluateJavascript(javascriptCode, new ValueCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String response) {
                Log.i("debug_log", response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(javascriptCode);
    }
}
```

But it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying on API 19 or higher? If so you'll have to use `WebView#evalulateJavascript` instead of `WebView#loadUrl`

I always use this method to simplify and quicken things a bit

```
public void js(String code) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        this.evaluateJavascript(code, new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String response) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:" + code);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get **cannot resolve Method "evaluteJavascript"**

Comment: Are you sure you referenced it from `myWebView` instance instead of `this`?

Comment: I replaced `this` with "myWebView` now I get "Cannot resolve symbol ValueCallback"

Comment: I had to `import android.webkit.ValueCallback`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to use your code, I had to add another parameter "WebView view" to your function. I tried it but the javascript code is not called.

Comment: Are you sure you called `setJavascriptEnabled` on the webview's settings instance?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I just had to call the code with `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`. The code was executed but did not changed anything because it was executed before the DOM was ready...

**Solution:**

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    website = "https://www.blizz-z.de";
    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.blizzView);

    WebSettings settings = blizzView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        // Notify the host application that a page has finished loading.
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            js(myWebView, "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" +
                        "setInterval(function() {" +
                            + "jQuery('#myInput').css('background', '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));"
                        + "}, 1000);"
                    + "});"
            );
        }
    }

    ...

}

public void js(WebView view, String code)
{
    String javascriptCode = "javascript:" + code;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        view.evaluateJavascript(javascriptCode, new ValueCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String response) {
                Log.i("debug_log", response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(javascriptCode);
    }
}
```

Credits to @mohkamfer for contributing the `js` function.

Comment: That's great, as a rule of thumb always print/log a statement to make sure everything is working!

Comment: @mohkamfer, yes I was setting a breakpoint and debugged the app. But I thought the JS is not working at all because nothing happened even though your js function was entered and evaluateJavascript was called.